# Java String Switch Statement Not Going To Proper Switch

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement

I'm currently facing an issue with my switch statement. I've printed out the switch variable, and it seems correct, but a print statement into the desired switch is not working. The switch statement is in the main ~20 lines from the bottom.

The test stub is:

```
"Person#Joe Gaucho#28000 Marguerite Parkway#949-582-4800#gaucho@sb.edu;"
"Faculty#1234153524#1341244#1234150000#Adjunct;Employee#bgs210#20000#123455000;"
"Person#Mickey Mouse#Disneyland#800 1Disney#mmouse@disney.com;"
"Exit#"
```

The expected output is:

```
Person      name: Joe Gaucho        address: 28000 Marguerite Parkway      phoneNumber: 949-582-4800        emailAddress: gaucho@sb.edu
Faculty OfficeHours: Wed Jan 14 22:49:13 PST 1970, Wed Dec 31 16:22:21 PST 1969, Wed Jan 14 22:49:10 PST 1970   rank: Adjunct
Employee        office: bgs210  salary: 20000.0 dateHired: Fri Jan 02 02:17:35 PST 1970
Person  name: Mickey Mouse      address: Disneyland     phoneNumber: 800 1DisneyemailAddress: mmouse@disney.com
```

And my output is:

```
Person  name: Joe Gaucho    address: 28000 Marguerite Parkway   phoneNumber: 949-582-4800   emailAddress: gaucho@sb.edu
Person  name: Joe Gaucho    address: 28000 Marguerite Parkway   phoneNumber: 949-582-4800   emailAddress: gaucho@sb.edu
Employee    noffice: bgs210 salary: 20000.0 dateHired: 123455000
Employee    noffice: bgs210 salary: 20000.0 dateHired: 123455000
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise10_2M {
    static class Person{
        String name;
        String address;
        String phoneNumber;
        String emailAddress;

        Person(){}
        Person(String name, String address, String phoneNumber, String email){
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            this.emailAddress = email;
        }

        @Override 
        public String toString(){
            return "Person\tname: " + name
                    + "\taddress: " + address
                    + "\tphoneNumber: " + phoneNumber
                    + "\temailAddress: " + emailAddress + "\n";
        }
    }
    static class Student extends Person{
        String classStatus; // freshmen, sophomore, sophomore+, junior, or senior

        Student(){}
        Student(/*String str1, String str2, String str3, String str4,*/ String str5){
            //super(str1, str2, str3, str4);
            classStatus = str5;
        }
        @Override 
        public String toString(){
            return "Student\tclassStatus: "+ classStatus + "\n" /*+ super.toString()*/;
        }
    }
    static class Employee extends Person{
        String office;
        double salary;
        long dateHired;
        Employee(){}
        Employee(String str, double doub, long long1){
            office = str;
            salary = doub;
            dateHired = long1;
        }
        @Override 
        public String toString(){
            return "Employee\tnoffice: " + office
                    + "\tsalary: " + salary
                    + "\tdateHired: " + dateHired + "\n";
        }
    }
    static class Faculty extends Employee{
        long[] officeHours;
        String rank;        // either adjunct, assistantProfessor, or Professor

        Faculty(){}
        // !!!! FIX

        /*Faculty(long long1, String str){
            officeHours = long1;
            rank = str;
        }*/

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Faculty\tofficeHours: " //+ officeHours[0]
                    + "\trank: " + rank + "\n";
        }
    }
    static class Staff extends Employee{
        String title;

        Staff(){}
        Staff(String str){
            title = str;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Staff\ttitle: " + title + "\n";
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner firstScan = new Scanner(System.in); // Scanner
        String firstInput;                          // Parses from scanner
        String[] myInput;                           // Parses from firstInput
        Person myClass = new Person();              // Class instance
        String typeOfPerson = new String();         // Holds value for which class
        boolean LCV = true;

        firstScan.useDelimiter(";");

        do{
            firstInput = firstScan.next();
            myInput = firstInput.split("#");
            typeOfPerson = myInput[0];

            switch(typeOfPerson){
                case "Person":   myClass = new Person(myInput[1], myInput[2],
                                                      myInput[3], myInput[4]);
                                           break;
                case "Student":  myClass = new Student(/*scan.next(), scan.next(),
                                                       scan.next(), scan.next(),*/
                                                       myInput[1]);
                                           break;
                case "Employee": myClass = new Employee(myInput[1],            
Double.parseDouble(myInput[2]), Long.parseLong(myInput[3])); 
                                           break;
                case "Faculty":  System.out.println("check");
                    //myClass = new Faculty();
                                           break;
                case "Staff":    myClass = new Staff(myInput[1]);
                                           break;
                case "Exit": LCV = false;
                                   break;
            }
            if(LCV == true){
                System.out.print(myClass.toString());
            } 
        }while(firstScan.hasNext() && LCV == true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm too assume your test stub is one big string that you're parsing, including the `"`?

Comment: Not causing your problem, but why all the `static` classes?

Comment: Yes it's all one big string. It doesn't include the quotation marks, but I was having trouble putting it into stack overflow without it because of the semicolon delimiters.

Comment: @Mickey It wouldn't work in the main without the static. I think it's because of the toString override from the object class.

Comment: Typically, as little as possible is done in main(). You could move much of the code in main() to a constructor in Exercise10_2M

Comment: What happens if you use `nextLine` instead of `next` for the Scanner?

Comment: I would sugguest you put breakpoints in and use the debugger to track the problem down a bit more. Put at breakpoint in the do-while loop so you can see the value of first input and the value of type of person you get everytime.

Comment: @mdewitt Okay thanks. It's taking in the /n and feeding it into variable typeOfPerson, so it's comparing /nsomevalue instead of somevalue.

Comment: This could have prevented, when having a `default:` and (maybe against your style guide of CS) declare variables at their usage: `Person myClass = null;` before the switch. _Please make your own answer_, so people won't any longer try to read the question.

Comment: @JoopEggen Okay I'll do that next time. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the value of `myClass` to some default value (commonly `null`) at the end of each loop. You're getting this repeated output because:

- It finds an input of type `Person`
- It updates `myClass` with a new `Person` object.
- Loop goes from the top, finds a new `Faculty`
- `myClass` isn't overwritten, ergo `Person` remains and it is outputted again.

I've replicated this behaviour in [this IDEOne](http://ideone.com/PISKD2).